# Host the Visual Studio Report Designer so end-users can design reports

Tags: .net, reporting, report-designer

I'd like to re-host the Visual Studio Report Designer in my own application so that my end-users can use it to design new reports or edit existing reports.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead, look at [Report Builder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207008.aspx).

Report Builder is a standalone report designer application for designing reports for SQL Server Reporting Services. It has somewhat more of an end-user orientation, more like one of the Microsoft Office products than like Visual Studio.

It can be used to design just about any kind of report you could design using BIDS.

Comment: Can you expand on this at all?  It's collecting flags for being a link-only answer.

Comment: Looks like the right answer though. =P It's not exactly what I wanted - embedding the designer in my own application - but it's close enough to fulfill the business requirement.